# Require solve package for octave

Tags: package, octave

Where can I find the solve package for octave? I need to solve algebraic equations and ODEs. For example I've tried:

> > x = solve('x + 3 = 0')
> >     error: 'solve' undefined near line 1 column 5

Or:

퓧댬>> x =fsolve('x + 3 = 0')
error: Invalid call to fsolve.  Correct usage is:

-- Function File:  fsolve (FCN, X0, OPTIONS)
 -- Function File: [X, FVEC, INFO, OUTPUT, FJAC] = fsolve (FCN, ...)

Additional help for built-in functions and operators is
available in the online version of the manual.  Use the command
'doc ' to search the manual index.

Help and information about Octave is also available on the WWW
at http://www.octave.org and via the help@octave.org
mailing list.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [solving equation using octave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692490/solving-equation-using-octave)

Answer (score 0):

Octave itself doesn't contain a CAS system (but you can solve ODEs, see help lsode). You can install a symbolic toolbox like [octsympy](https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy).